# Is the solution of the method of equating coefficients a solution of infinite others?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this statement:

> Determine if it is true or false that in the system of equations:
>
> $ax+by=c$
>
> $dx+ey=f$
>
> If $c=f$ The system have infinite solutions.

My attempt was:

If $c=f \to ax+by=dx+ey$ and noting that the only elements that "generate" $x$ are $a,d$, then $ax=ad \to a=d$ and the same with $b,e \to b=e.$

Counterexample: But what happens when $a,b,d,e$ are not constant values, per example:

$a = (1+y)$ The equation will be $(1+y)x + by = dx +ey \to x +xy+by = dx+ey$

What I want to show is that, in this case, the coefficient $b$  is not the only one that "generates" $y$ so i can't say that $by = dy$ and thus $b \neq d$.

My question is more oriented to the process of [Equating coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equating_coefficients). In summary, this method only works to find one of the infinite possible solutions and does not ensure that it is the only solution, as I have stated in this exercise?

If the answer above is yes, then I could not assure you that, the solutions are always infinite, unless, it is indicated that the coefficients are numerical values, that is, they do not include within themselves the variables $(x, y)$ as I showed in the counterexample.

Comment: Are the coefficients integers, by the way?

Comment: @DietrichBurde in the set of $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is False. A counter example is $a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,f=3.$

The one and only solution in this case is $x=-3,y=3.$

I prefer using linear algebra to find the nature of solutions of a set of linear equations. It is a way better tool than precalculus algebra and gets the job done efficiently.

Comment: I understand, but linear algebra is still far away for me. I just want to know how this method works according to what I have already written in my question.